# UIView cocos2d Support

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm following a tutorial to add banner in my app, but I don't understand a thing, here:

"FOR SHOW **BannerView** FIRST CREATE A UIView AND ADD IT TO TOP OF ROOT UIView :

```
UIView *adView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:adRect]; 
         [[CCDirector sharedDirector].view addSubview:adView];
```

" THEN **ADD BannerView** TO IT:

```
[[MyAdMobController sharedController] addBannerToView:adView];
```

where he says to create a `UIView`, It means that I have to create a new scene? because i don't know exactly what is a `UIView` (i'm a beginner), someone can give me an example of what i have to do?

Comment: can u post the link where u are learning it

Comment: https://github.com/MrCapone/MyAdMobController-iOS

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a `UIView` to your Cocos2d project you have to add it to the window. The director creates and handles the main Window and the Cocos2D view. `CCDirector` inherits from `CC_VIEWCONTROLLER` which is equivalent to `UIViewController`. The `UIView` isn't a new scene it is a "visible object" that is added to your view via the `CCDirector`.

```
(your eyes)

adMobBanner
    |
  adView
    |
  Window

 (Device)
```

all you are really doing is creating a box to sit on top of the window for the banner to fit into.

Answer (score 0):

The cocos2d view is a view and everything it contains can only be "in" this cocos2d view so you need to create a layer above this cocos2d layer
I would suggest if you want to use UIkit to use CCUIViewWrapper

.h

```
 CCUIViewWrapper *wrapper;
@property (assign, nonatomic)CCUIViewWrapper *wrapper;
```

.m

```
#import "CCUIViewWrapper.h"

//create wrapper to hold UILabel above cocos2d layer
wrapper = [CCUIViewWrapper wrapperForUIView:label];
float padding = 10;
wrapper.contentSize = CGSizeMake(500+padding, label.frame.size.height/2+padding);
[self addChild:wrapper];
wrapper.position = ccp(size.width/2, size.height/2+label.frame.size.height/2);
```

look up github.com CCUIViewWrapper.h CCUIViewWrapper.m